# What are the disadvantages of purchasing pre-owned games for the Wii U?

Tags: wii-u

I have a Wii U and I want to buy some games. It's in the nature of console games, that they are expensive. So I think about buying pre-owned games.

Because the Nintendo Club is closing, I have no disadvantages that I will not have the Nintendo Club codes.

But is there something else which could be a drawback buying a pre-owned game, assuming, the disc is intact and an original one? There aren't any serial numbers or bounds to a console, right?

Comment: I wouldn't think so and even if so: it wouldn't be your fault, it would be the shop owner's fault who sold it to you. In other words, Keep the receipt. if you can't play it, get a refund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only new game I bought for my Wii U was Splatoon. I haven't noticed anything wrong with any of my other (used) games. I won't list them, but none of them require any sort of method that tie it to the original console. So I can't speak for every Wii U game released, but I haven't run into this issue with about 10 or so games.
The only possible issue I could see, is if a game had online components that were locked until you bought a online pass. Some (very few) PS4 and XBONE titles do this unfortunately (Resistance 3 comes to mind), but I have yet to see this on any Wii U games I own. And this would be a decision of the game developer/publisher (not sure who would make that call?)  and not of Nintendo in general, so you couldn't generalize for *all* used Wii U games.

Like Robotnik commented, if you do happen to find one that you can't play for that reason, return it. They have no business selling you something you can't use.